# Location Dot in Google Maps iOS SDK showing as a Square

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

In this image, the location dot has a white circle around it.

[image]

Anyone knows what can cause this ?

I am using the normal `self.gMap.myLocationEnabled = YES;`

Thank you

Comment: can you please share your code.

Answer (score 8):

I have the same issue and I foud [this](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5472) in the bug trackin of the SDK. It say in the real device works fine without square.